What is the cover time for a path?
This question seems simple enough but I could not find the proof that states for a path $P_n$, the cover time is $O(n^2)$. Say I denote the expected time for a graph $G = (V, E)$ to visit all of its nodes starting from $v$ is $\text{cover}_v(G)$, then the cover time is $\text{cover}(G) = \mathop{\max}\limits_{v \in V}\text{cover}_v(G)$
.Well I did find an exact solution (?), and although the proof seems sound, I am quite skeptical as it is not mentioned anywhere else.
I know that the expected time is maximized at the $\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$th vertex. I am not sure how to proceed from here to find the $\text{cover}(P_n)$.
Edit:.
For convenience, let $h_v := \text{cover}_v(G)$. We now have the following reoccurrence relation:
$$h_v = 0.5h_{v-1}+0.5h_{v+1}+1 \text{ for all } 1 < v < n;$$
$$h_1 = 1+h_2;$$
$$h_n = 1+h_{n-1}.$$
I guess from here we solve for $h_v$ and pick the maximum? If so, any pointers on how to solve it?

I don't think the conditions on $h$ values are well-formed; for example, for $n=3$ you have $h_1-h_2=1, h_3-h_2=1, h_1 - 2h_2 + h_3 = 2$, which is a linear system with linearly dependent rows. In particular, any values of the form $(t,t-1,t)$ fit this description.

Why must $h_1 = 1 + h_2$?  Certainly you travel from node $1$ to node $2$; but from there you only have to hit the nodes $> 2$, whereas if you were to start at node $2$, you'd have to hit those nodes plus node $1$.  (Indeed, for $n=3$ this can't possibly be right; you have $h_2 = 1 + h_1/2 + h_3/2 = 1+h_1$ by symmetry, and so can't also have $h_1 = 1+h_2$.)

Note that for a path $P_n$, any covering walk starting must first reach one end (node $1$ or node $n$) and then the other end; and conversely any walk that does those two things is a covering walk.  Moreover, it doesn't matter which end is reached first (by symmetry).  So we can say that the expected time $h_v(n)=T_v(n) + S_1(n)$, where $T_v(n)$ is the expected time to reach either end starting from node $v$, and $S_v(n)$ is the expected time to reach node $n$ starting from node $v$.
Each of these satisfies the same linear recurrence, with different boundary conditions.  For the former,
$$
T_1(n)=T_n(n)=0; \qquad T_v(n)=1+\frac{1}{2}\left(T_{v-1}(n) + T_{v+1}(n)\right) \;\; [v\neq 1,n].
$$
For the latter,
$$
S_n(n)=0; \qquad S_1(n)=1+S_2(n); \qquad S_v(n)=1+\frac{1}{2}\left(S_{v-1}(n) + S_{v+1}(n)\right) \;\;[v\neq 1,n].
$$
The general solution is $K_v = -v^2 + \alpha v + \beta$.  Including the boundary conditions, we find that $$T_v(n)=\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)^2 - \left(v - \frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2$$
and that
$$
S_v(n)=-v^2+2v+n^2-2n,
$$
so $S_1(n)=(n-1)^2$.  Putting it together,
$$
h_v(n)=\frac{5}{4}(n-1)^2 -\left(v - \frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2;
$$
this is maximized at $v=\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor$ and $v=\lceil(n+1)/2\rceil$, where it takes the value $\frac{5}{4}(n-1)^2$ (if $n$ is odd) or $\frac{5}{4}(n-1)^2 - \frac{1}{4}$ (if $n$ is even).  This yields $0$ for $n=1$ and $1$ for $n=2$, as it must, and is asymptotic to $5n^2/4$ for large $n$.

@MishaLavrov: Quite right, thanks!  I think it should be corrected now.
